# Office API call to getUserIdentityTokenAsync() returns a null token

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Our Outlook add-in runs successfully for our production clients except for one specific tenant.

With this one tenant, the Office API call to `getUserIdentityTokenAsync()` returns a null token.

Here is what I have determined from reviewing our logs:

1. When they access the addin from the Mac Outlook client, getUserIdentityTokenAsync() returns "Status" = "failed" with error code "9017".
2. When they access the addin from Chrome or Firefox, getUserIdentityTokenAsync() returns "Status" = "succeeded" but the token value is null.

Their self-hosted Microsoft Exchange server version is `15.1.1531.3` and I have confirmed `Exchange Web Services` is enabled.

Does anyone have insight as to why this method is failing to return a token?

Comment: What permissions did you specify in the manifest for your add-in? Does updating to the latest CU fix this issue?

Comment: What version of Mac Outlook is seeing this call fail?

Comment: Adam, I noticed you posted something similar in October 2017, is it the same outstanding issue since then?  I'm not sure what could be relevant in particular, but first thing that comes to my mind is if authentication flow is different -- do they authenticate directly to cloud, or do they get redirected to on-prem ADFS or other means, etc.  Is there something different between this tenant and the others in terms of authentication.  Do they have matching UPNs etc., etc. between on-prem and AAD.  Grasping at anything here.

Comment: Look at the Fiddler trace / browser debugger to see what the response is to the request https://<server>/owa/service.svc?action=GetClientAccessToken&EP=xxxx&ID=xxxx&AC=xxxx, maybe it will shed some light on it if there is a particular error in getting the client access token.

Comment: Here is the permissions xml tag in our manifest `<Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>`.  The client is on exchange version `15.1.1531.3`, is there a more recent version of Exchange 2016?

Comment: The version of Mac Outlook seeing the 9017 error is `16.17 (180909.1)`

Comment: Brian, this issue does not seem to be related to my previous question. The previous time we were seeing this problem was coming from multiple different tenants and only using Outlook clients that were known to have issues with that api call. 

This issue is only affecting one client (all users for this one client, all platforms).

I will work on getting the fiddler trace tomorrow. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @BrianClink I went through a fiddler trace with the user and the response to the GetClientAccessToken endpoint is a 200 with six items returned in the body with the following exception:

   `{
        "__type": "GetClientAccessTokenResponseMessage:#Exchange",
        "MessageText": "The token for this extension could not be retrieved.",
        "ResponseCode": "ErrorInvalidClientAccessTokenRequest",
        "ResponseClass": "Error",
        "Token": null
    }`

Since my last post, they have upgraded to version `15.1.1591.10`. Their authentication is on-prem.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Can you advise on next steps? Should we open a support ticket for this specific issue?